# Explosions and fireflies / dots in Blender 2.8 (already followed all tutorial without results)

Tags: rendering, denoise, fire

Good morning everyone,

I'm literally ready to pay who will be able to solve my problem.

**here is the original file of the explosion.**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UBb2ctIG_OQ5qh7bpMSTUFcNI_E1LTCq/view?usp=sharing

**Blender 2.8
Cycles**

[image: **In the screenshot here you can see, literally too many fireflies**]

PROBLEM: FIREFLIES, STILL A LOT OF THEM IN RENDERING.

Everytime I use fire / explosion I cant get those fireflies away in the rendering.
Already followed all tutorials/discussions/youtubevideos about deleting fireflies in rendering.
Already tried everything without finding a solution (*clamp, light size, hundreds of samples, caustics, filter glossy, glossy bounces, multiple importance*).

The denoiser helps but it really makes a lot of damage to my scene, so I would want to try avoid it for now, and for sure this scene can get a lot better before I will put the denoiser as a last touch. But for sure for now there is still too much fireflies/dots!

Please open the original file and help me find a solution !!
It does that everytime I work with fire/explosions.
With smokes I can fix the problem, but when it comes to fire here they appear without solutions!

Thank you very much for helping

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this without denoising is increasing the number of samples up to about 2500. It takes a long time to render, but your image stays crisp.

Comment: please try to do it using my .blend file? Because I really have the suspect that those fireflies are not the ones that goes away when you use crazy amount of samples, but I dont know ..
Thanks for your reply in any case !!
-
[Ah, I dont have modern GTX graphic cards or similar that allows me to use 2500 samples in an explosion scene, would take 14 days for 1 frame, this is the reason why I ask you to try that please! xD ]

Answer (score -3):

Use embergen to create flip book, composite in later. Fake the lighting from explosion in composite as well.